# Why does my click handler only work for the first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
var hitarea = $("#c_" + $.fragment().category).parent().siblings('div.hitarea');
var arr = new Array();
arr.push(hitarea);

do{
  hitarea = $(hitarea.parent().parent().siblings('div.hitarea'));
  arr.splice(0,0,hitarea);
}while(hitarea.length > 0);

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var element = $(arr[i]);
  if(arr[i].length != 0){
    element.trigger('click');
  }
}
```

But this only works for the first element, and the click event of the following elements is not triggered.

Help.

Comment: What happens on the click of the first element? Is there a reload of the page or change of context?

Comment: I am implementing the jquery treeview plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/ and if a user specifies a particular node id then I have to open the tree till that node

Comment: Rohit, it would be great if you'd resolve this question so it doesn't keep bubbling up. if you've abandoned it, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr=[...]//array of elements

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var element = $(arr[i]);
  if(element.length){
    element.trigger('click');
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. You had forgotten to close the outer for loop
2. There is no need to check if `!= 0` - 0 is one of JavaScript's "falsey" values, so just putting the variable name will check if it is not zero, not null, not undefined, etc.
3. If `arr` is already an array of jQuery objects, then there is no need to wrap it in the jQuery object again (i.e. don't do `$(arr[i])`). If it is a normal DOM element or sub-array, though, then my code above will work.

Comment: You don't even need the `if (element.length)` check - jQuery will happily do nothing if the selector set is empty. For instance, `$('#idthatdoesntexist').click()` just does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(arr[i].length != 0){
```

Is that { a typo? If not, that would explain the problem.